# Connecting to monogdb with string

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to connect to MongoDB using a `MONGO_URL:`. This particular database has a username and password. I've created a user to allow readWrite commands and that's the one I'm using.

If I log into the database and use `show dbs` this is what appears:

```
admin         0.000GB
myspecial_db  0.000GB
local         0.000GB
```

I'm trying to access the `myspecial_db`.

`MONGO_URL: mongodb://username:password@private-network-ip:27017/myspecial_db`

When I try and launch my app I get this error in terminal.

`MongoError: failed to connect to server [private-network-ip:27017]`

What am I missing here?

Comment: Here a few quick things to check: Firewall settings, network proxy settings, double-quoting the connection string, the MongoDB database log. When you successfully connect to the database are you on the client (App side) or on the server?

Comment: When it works, as in a no firewall no username and password, it is connecting from the app side. This error is confusing `Failed to connect to 172.17.0.2 port 80`

Comment: @bp123, What is MongoDB version(x,y,z)?

Comment: It's MongoDB 3.4

Comment: In your comment you have mentioned *port 80*, Probably you are trying to access your application on web server and not the MongoDB. You need to try connecting to mongo shell from your application server and share the log. Alternatively you can directly share mongodb server log when you have attempted connection from your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mention your error like

> MongoError: failed to connect to server [private-network-ip:27017]

This error is what you would see if the mongo shell was not able to talk to the mongod server.

As per MongoDB documentation [Connection String URI Format](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/) The URI format for defining connections between applications and MongoDB instances in the official MongoDB [drivers](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/drivers/).

The following is the standard URI connection scheme:

```
mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]]
```

For further your ref [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html)

Answer (score 0):

The problem I had wasn't related to the MONGO_URL it was related to server setup. I had blocked all incoming traffic using a firewall and the open port was incorrect.